# FileUpload upload codebehind.

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

How can i upload with FileUpload codebehind only? My controls are made codebehind because i have Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged and need to generate various numbers of controls. I can list the controls fine and attach file and text to txtbox with:

```
        private void SetChildrenCountControls(int total)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
          {
            var tbBirthDate = new TextBox();
            tbBirthDate.ID = "tbBirthDate_" + (i + 1);
            tbBirthDate.CssClass = "tbSister_input";
            tbBirthDate.EnableViewState = true;

            FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
            upload.ID = "imgUpload_" + (i + 1);
            upload.CssClass = "tbSister_upload";
            upload.EnableViewState = true;

            ChildrenCountTextPanel.Controls.Add(tbBirthDate);
            ChildrenCountTextPanel.Controls.Add(upload);
          }
       }
```

And can get the enterede text in the txtbox with:

```
         protected void lbFamilySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var countSisters = ChildrenCountTextPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
        string sisterBirth = string.Empty;
        foreach (var sister in countSisters)
        {
            if (sister.ID.Contains("tbBirthDate_"))
                sisterBirth = sister.Text;
        }
    }
```

How can i get the file from the FileUpload controls? Cant seem to do above with FileUpload.

Comment: You need to store the FileUpload reference as a global variable, add the controls on preinit or init; when the postback happens after file upload, the control should then have the posted file information in the PostedFile property.

Comment: Have you tried adding upload.RunAt = "server"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the click event below you are getting TextBoxes and not FileUpload Control

```
btn_protected void lbFamilySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var countSisters = ChildrenCountTextPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

A file upload control is of this type  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload`

So please get the FileUpload control then do the following:

```
if (myFileUpload.HasFile)
{
  string savePath = @"C:\Temp\" + myFileUpload.FileName;

  myFileUpload.SaveAs(savePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this, thought i had tryed that. Apparently not good enough :)

```
 var countUploads = ChildrenCountTextPanel.Controls.OfType<FileUpload>();

        FileUpload FileUl = new FileUpload();
        foreach (var ul in countUploads)
        {
            if(ul.ID.Contains("imgUpload_"))
            {
                FileUl = ul;               
            }
        }
if (FileUl.HasFile)
{
 ConvertAndSave(FileUl)
 }
```